# Converting varbinary to image in silverlight (part 2)

Tags: c#, silverlight, image, byte, varbinary

I am trying to convert a varbinary to an image in my silverlight project.

First I get the Binary from my database in my service.

```
    [OperationContract]
    public byte[] getAfbeelding(int id)
    {

        var query = (from p in dc.Afbeeldings
                     where p.id == id
                     select p.source).Single();

        byte[] source = query.ToArray();
```

Then I try to convert the varbinary to an image, using code found on StackOverflow:

```
    public static string convertToImage(byte[] source)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(source);
        Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
        return img.Source.ToString();
    }
```

But as it turns out, the silverlight `Image` does not have a `.FromStream`, I tried all the examples found in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623264/how-to-convert-varbinary-into-image-or-video-when-retrieved-from-database-in-c-s) but NONE of them work in silverlight.

```
'System.Windows.Controls.Image' does not contain a definition for 'FromStream'
```

So yeah, I'm kinda lost and am not sure what to do.
Any ideas on how to do this in silverlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost right. The following code should be all you need:

```
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
bitmapImage.SetSource(new MemoryStream(imageData));
newImage.Source = bitmapImage;
```

where `imageData` is of type `byte[]` and `newImage` is the image you want to update.

Comment: Thank you! This worked! :D 
Is there any way I can return the source in a method? I want to create a seperate class to handle the converting so I just need the source.

Comment: I can just return the bitmapImage, that seems to work, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

you sould have a look at WriteableBitmap.

there is a pretty nice set of extensions freely available on [codepelex](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) or [Nuget](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/WriteableBitmapEx)

Comment: Thanks for the helpful link but I managed to make it work with the previous answer.