# Tool/method to convert a varbinary to an image file

Tags: sql, image, sql-server-2008, type-conversion

I have a table in a SQL Server 2008 with images (JPG) stored in a varbinary column. I was wondering if there's a really simple way of converting a varbinary back to a image file.

For example - I'm using Management Studio, and I am able to just right click on my "cell" with the data in hex format (0xFFD8FFDB0084... etc.) I can paste that sting into a text file. Is there a nice tool to execute on that text file to convert it to a binary file?

Unfortunately, i DO NOT have any EXECUTE permission on this database... (Otherwise I would have been able to use BCP.)

Comment: I'm not sure why you can't use bcp, it just [needs `SELECT` permission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) on the table. Otherwise, you can just write a small script or application that queries the table data and saves the results as a binary file; how to do that depends on the programming language ([this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623264/how-to-convert-varbinary-into-image-or-video-when-retrieved-from-database-in-c-s) shows one way for C#).

Comment: @Superhubert one limitation with your use case is that Mgmt Studio has a limit on the output of a column; if your varbinary is over 65K it would be truncated.

Comment: @SqlACID - you're absolutely right about that (of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most convenient method of extracting images from my database was to use a PowerShell script [explained here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/890.export-sql-server-blob-data-with-powershell.aspx)

As mentioned by @SqlACID, simply copying the data from the column i SQL Management Studio would truncate the varbinary to 65K.